# docker-compose: .env file is not loaded

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    build: .
```

My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine:latest
ENTRYPOINT echo $ARG1 $ARG2
```

My `.env` file

```
ARG1=argument100
ARG2=argument200
```

If I run `docker-compose run test` the empty line got printed. However, it I add `env_file` section to my `docker-compose.yml` I am getting the expected output.

New `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  test:
    build: .
    env_file:
    - .env
```

Running `docker-compose` again

```
$ docker-compose run test
argument100 argument200
```

Am I using an illegal way to pass arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT` command inside the `Docker`? Why is `.env` not loaded automatically upon `docker-compose run`?

Answer (score 0):

The `.env` file is used to set variables in the docker-compose command itself that can be used to expand variables in the docker-compose.yml file itself. The `env_file` specification will define variables inside the containers. They operate at two different levels.

There's also a third type of variable, build args, that can be injected into the building of an image.

Each of these has a distinct purpose, and are not multiple ways to do the same thing.